# If a word starts with a number, does capitalization apply to the first letter?

Tags: notation, article-writing

If a mathematical word begins with a number and a hyphen, such as "4-dimensional" or $3-manifold," and this word occurs at the beginning of a sentence, should you capitalize the first letter?

For example, which is correct?

3-dimensional space is nice.

or

3-Dimensional space is nice.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on English SE?

Comment: No but math does not necessarily follow the same conventions, and words of this nature are uncommon in ordinary English. Consider the fact that in the title of a math talk or math article, often only the first word is capitalized whereas everywhere else (I know of) all main words are capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

The convention in mathematical writing is to never begin a sentence with a mathematical symbol, so as to avoid this ambiguity. Instead of writing, "$5$-dimensional manifolds have the disjoint disks property," or  "$5$-Dimensional manifolds have the disjoint disks property," I would write "Five dimensional manifolds have the disjoint disks property." This removes all ambiguity. Instead of writing "$f$ is a continuous function," I would write "The function $f$ is continuous."

Though I have no personal experience in professional editing, I am told that editors in general (meaning even outside of mathematics and science) find ways to reword sentences to avoid the ambiguities that arise frequently in English, and, I assume, other languages.

Comment: Many people instead follow the convention of never starting a sentence with a mathematical symbol, if the previous sentence ended in a mathematical symbol. For instance "The domain of the function is $D$. $R$ is its range," would be disallowed but "$D$ is the function's domain. $R$ is its range," would be okay. Anyway, consider in particular if the name of a talk is "$3$-manifolds and number theory" (or "$3$-Manifolds and number theory"). I feel one should not have to change the $3$ to a "Three" to be grammathematically correct.

Comment: If they do, I haven't noticed, which probably speaks to this policy being okay. I also think that the title of a talk, or even an article is a different animal than a sentence in the body of an article, especially since the titles (like the one you suggest) are often not sentences. I wouldn't be offended if you titled your talk this way.

Comment: Which way, with the "m" or the "M"? (I guess maybe you wouldn't be offended either way, but which seems more correct?)

Comment: The capital "M" seems better to me.

Comment: I think I've just been starring at it too long. Maybe I'll just call the thing "Number theory and 3-manifolds." Ha!

Comment: I suppose most publications exempt titles from at least some of the requirements of style that sentences must follow. Looking over the titles in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles, I was struck by how few this question applied to; they either started with a word or were composed entirely of symbols, except for one at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles/44348#44348 and possibly the one at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles/44330#44330 -- and neither capitalizes the first English word, which is "is" in both cases.

Comment: It seems easier to find chemistry papers that start with something other than a capital letter. The ones I found that weren't all in "title case" seemed to capitalize the first word they could and none thereafter. Personally I find that a bit jarring and would have preferred nothing be capitalized.